# SQL Linked server - Remote access error when executing SP

Tags: sql, sql-server, linked-server

I've set up a linked server between an instance on SQL 2012 and SQL 2008R2 but 
I keep getting the below error when trying to execute a stored procedure on a remote server:

```
 Msg 7201, Level 17, State 4, Line 1
Could not execute procedure on remote server 'TEST' because SQL Server is not configured for remote access. Ask your system administrator to reconfigure SQL Server to allow remote access.
```

I've checked on both servers and they're configured to allow remote connections. The login that I've used has sysadmin access on the remote server and I can see all the databases when I expand 'Catalogs' within the linked server. When I test the connection this also says it's connected successfully. The SQL Service account also has SA on both instances for what it's worth

The odd thing is when I run a simple select query on one of the tables within the database it shows a result but it doesn't seem to like the SP.

```
Select * from Linkserver.database.dbo.table
```

The above works fine but this SP doesn't:

```
EXECUTE  Linkedserver.database.[dbo].[SP] ....
```

Any recommendation would be appreciated.

Comment: Try---> exec nameofyourSP 'remote access', 1
 reconfigure

Answer (score 4):

Despite being an old thread, forget about enabling remote access (and restart service) on remote server and try:

```
EXECUTE (N'database.[dbo].[SP]') AT Linkedserver
```

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run SPs from Server B, then make Server B as the linked server in server A.

Run the script below in **Server A**, not B:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', 1; RECONFIGURE;
```

Then restart SQL Service in A.
Done.

Answer (score 1):

First Run:

```
EXEC sp_configure 'remote access', '1';

RECONFIGURE;
```

You now need to restart MSSQLSERVER in order for the `sp_configure` command to take effect.

Once you restart it, run `sp_configure` again and notice that the `run_value` is 1 now. That's what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please first check your server properties if remote connections is allowed (related picture below). IF yes, use:  `exec nameofyourSP 'remote access', 1 reconfigure` and try again.

[image]